# Integration, question about constant value $c$

Tags: calculus

If the integral of $f(x)$ is $\frac{4}{3}(x+c)$ and I have to expand this equation, then can I ignore the constant value and say it is equal to $\frac{4}{3}x+c$, or am I required to state that it is equal to $\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{4}{3}c$

Since the constant value will never be known, is the first answer acceptable, or must I use the second i.e. $\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{4}{3}c$

Comment: You are totally right : it is just a constant. If you prefer, define $d=4c/3$

Comment: Be careful not to think that $c$ is fixed, as your use of "the constant value" implies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just ignore the terms in front of the constant.

In fact, since $c$ is an unknown constant, you can just set $c_1 = \frac 43 c$  and use $c_1$ as your new constant.  You can do so for every function $f(c)$ (that does not limit the range of values the constant can take), for example $\frac 43 c, 2 + 5c, c^3-1$ etc.

Comment: $\ln|c|$? what if $c=0$

Comment: @Darksonn right! Edited

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the 4/3. It's included in the constant.